# Power BI DAX to add extra row for each customer after their last transaction, but increment their date by a month

Tags: dax

I want to get a subset of this table that includes the last transaction record for each customer (in this case the bolded rows), increment the OrderDate by 1 month, then append this to the existing table.

here is my example table

**Name  Date    Amt**
CUSTA   Jan 2023    10
CUSTA   Feb 2023    10
**CUSTA Mar 2023    10**
CUSTB   Nov 2022    10
CUSTB   Dec 2022    10
CUSTB   Jan 2023    10
CUSTB   Feb 2023    10
**CUSTB Mar 2023    10**
CUSTC   Nov 2022    10
CUSTC   Dec 2022    10
**CUSTC Jan 2023    10**

the additional rows to add would be

**CUSTA Apr 2023    10**
**CUSTB Apr 2023    10**
**CUSTC Feb 2023    10**

Final step would then to set the Amt to zero for these rows.

It should have been very straight forward, but i have struggled.

I have managed to get a subset (the bolded 3 rows) with a filter function

FILTER(table,'table'[Date] = CALCULATE(MAX('table'[Date]), ALLEXCEPT('table', 'table'[Name]))), but struggled to increment the Date (tried DateAdd), but it seems that if the filtered table is in a variable, it does recognises the columns.

THis is part of a process to calc the Status of each customer at any given month (no change, increase, decrease, Churn, New), which i would implement by comparing Amt with previous month's value (assumed the table will be sorted by customer and date)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to compare sales compared to previous month using a measure like this one instead, which could be modified to express if the customer is new etc as well.

```
Sales compared to last month = 
VAR current_month = MAX('Calendar'[DateKey])
VAR sales_current_month =
    CALCULATE(
        sum(Sales[SalesAmount]),
        VALUES('Calendar'[Year]),
        VALUES('Calendar'[MonthName])
    )
VAR sales_previous_month =
    CALCULATE(
        sum(Sales[SalesAmount]),
        PREVIOUSMONTH('Calendar'[DateKey])
    )
VAR result_for_month_level_only =
    IF(
        ISFILTERED('Calendar'[MonthName]),
        sales_current_month - sales_previous_month
    )
RETURN result_for_month_level_only
```

[image: result]